# Select com exceção de valores (SQL / Oracle)

Tags: sql, sql-server, oracle

Preciso aprimorar este select que ja existe aqui para realizar uma consulta onde não sejam retornados os ICCID iniciados por 8995, porém não tenho muito conhecimento de banco de dados.

Como posso alterar este select? Eu utilizo o SQLDEVELOPER, porém o banco do cliente provavelmente é Oracle.

```
SELECT a.rp_package_value AS ICCID,
  c.rrs_resource_value AS IMSI,
  (
  CASE
    WHEN (SUBSTR (c.rrs_resource_value, 6, 1) = SUBSTR (a.rp_package_value, 9, 1))
    AND (SUBSTR (c.rrs_resource_value, 6, 2) <> '00') -- valida se o HLR existe
    THEN 'Valid'
    ELSE 'Invalid'
  END ) AS IMSI_CHECK ,
  rrs_resource_sts Status, rp_package_sts
FROM rm_packages a,
  rm_package_content b,
  rm_resource_stock c
WHERE a.rp_package_value IN
  (SELECT RRS_RESOURCE_VALUE
  FROM rm_resource_stock c
  WHERE c.rrs_resource_tp_id = 6
  AND c.rrs_resource_pool = 30
  --AND a.rp_package_value like '89955053110002178148'
  AND SUBSTR (RRS_RESOURCE_VALUE, 9, 1) = '1' 
  AND c.rrs_resource_sts = 'ASSIGNED' 

  )
AND a.rp_package_id = b.rpc_package_id
AND c.rrs_resource_sts = a.rp_package_sts
AND b.rpc_component_tp_id = 5
AND b.rpc_component_vl_id = c.rrs_id
ORDER BY a.sys_creation_date DESC;
```

[image: Buscar]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Você pode simplesmente adicionar essa condição no seu `WHERE`

```
WHERE a.rp_package_value NOT LIKE '8995%'
```

**`'8995%'`** - Procura por tudo que começa com 8995...

**`LIKE`** - Procura por uma string parecida

**`NOT`** - Nega o `Like`

Seu SELECT final será:

```
SELECT a.rp_package_value AS ICCID,
  c.rrs_resource_value AS IMSI,
  (
  CASE
    WHEN (SUBSTR (c.rrs_resource_value, 6, 1) = SUBSTR (a.rp_package_value, 9, 1))
    AND (SUBSTR (c.rrs_resource_value, 6, 2) <> '00') -- valida se o HLR existe
    THEN 'Valid'
    ELSE 'Invalid'
  END ) AS IMSI_CHECK ,
  rrs_resource_sts Status, rp_package_sts
FROM rm_packages a,
  rm_package_content b,
  rm_resource_stock c
WHERE a.rp_package_value IN
  (SELECT RRS_RESOURCE_VALUE
  FROM rm_resource_stock c
  WHERE c.rrs_resource_tp_id = 6
  AND c.rrs_resource_pool = 30
  AND a.rp_package_value NOT LIKE '8995%' /* aqui */
  AND SUBSTR (RRS_RESOURCE_VALUE, 9, 1) = '1' 
  AND c.rrs_resource_sts = 'ASSIGNED' 

  )
AND a.rp_package_id = b.rpc_package_id
AND c.rrs_resource_sts = a.rp_package_sts
AND b.rpc_component_tp_id = 5
AND b.rpc_component_vl_id = c.rrs_id
ORDER BY a.sys_creation_date DESC;
```